# Why does Springs @Required not work when configured by annotations

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, required

I wonder if there is a way to get @Required working when doing the configuration by annotations. I turned my configuration up-and-down and back again but nothing seems to work for me. I'm using Spring 3.1
My basic configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    public MailSender mailSender() {
        MailSender MailSender = new MailSender();
        // mailSender.setBean(dlMailSender);
        return mailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
        // setting som props
        return myBean;
    }
}
```

MailSender is here:

```
@Configurable
public class MailSender {
    private MyBean myBean;
    @Required
    public void setMyBean(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }
}
```

I'm testing it with this junit:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpringConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MailSenderTest {
    @Test
    public void test_main_beans_exists() {
        // when  then  given
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where is `MyBean` defined?

Comment: Because when using `@Configuration` class with `@Bean` the scanning for `@Required` (for those beans) is disabled. (Why I cannot tell you). See [the code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java#L195). My guess as to why is that due to the proxies created for the `@Bean` methods this might be needed to do.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using @Autowired?

Comment: @M.Deinum: do you know a way how to bypass this?

Comment: @Steve: actually not really. I just aligned to the existing style of that project

Comment: My understanding is that the \@Required annotation is there to throw errors if you didn't inject a required bean property properly. Handy as a check if you're doing all your injection in XML. But if you want beans to be injected automatically, that's what \@Autowired (or \@Resource) is designed for.

Comment: Instead of `@Required` simply use constructor based injection, this makes sure you cannot create an invalid instance (and you could do null checks in the constructor). Basically `@Required` IMHO is bad because you should really be using constructor injection instead (but that is IMHO ofcourse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - **this is not even theoretically possible**.

When using XML-based, bean definitions with their dependencies are completely managed by application context. Spring is able to check, what is being set and what is not being set.

When using annotation-based configuration, you are setting the dependencies yourself. There is no way how Spring can even know what you are doing with the bean before returning it from the factory method.

---

If you want to check whether the bean is correctly initialized, use `InitializingBean` or `@PostConstruct` and implement self-checking method. Spring is doing this regularly in its own beans.